# Has anyone been able to utilize danfojs-node package on an m1 chip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, npm

I was trying to utilize danfojs-node on a mac running an M1 chip but it crashes due to TensorFlow and I was wondering if anyone was able to successfully utilize the npm package located here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/danfojs-node) with a current node.js project.  If so, how?  Otherwise, does anyone know a good alternative for building graphs in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

step 0: arch -arm64 zsh

step 1: nvm install 16 (17 works as well)

step 2: install danfojs-node@1.0.2

Then you good.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been better about my initial question.  I am running Node version 12 and my dependencies run based on that version.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately all node versions not supporting arm64 do not work.